# How to centre menu items on horizontal nav bar? (e.g. make margins equal)

Tags: menus, css, links

I'm currently working on building this site:

http://2013.whitehallrow.com/

I would like to centre the menu items so that there isn't the large gap after "Row Club" on the right. I've tried to locate the section in style.css that deals with the menu, but I can't find it... how do I do this?

Comment: CSS questions are [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the ".main-navigation li" (line 1487) from css, you put {padding: 0 24px; margin:0px; position: relative;}, and remove anything else.

This should do the trick.

--- or ---

you move the top and bottom borders on the menu-nav-bar-container div, and you remove the borders and width from the ul.

This shoud do the trick too.